# Selecting largest feature within each feature using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, select

I need to select the largest feature within another feature using Arcmap 10.3.

I have two sets of data, building footprints and land parcels. Generally there is a many to one relationship where there are many building footprints within one land parcel.

I would like to select the building footprint with the largest floor area in each land parcel. Resulting in a one to one relationship.

As I am working with 7000 building footprints and 5000 land parcels, I would like to find a way to automate this however I do not have a lot of knowledge on scripting. I can use ModelBuilder.

Below is an example of the data. Building footprint pink and land parcels black:

[image: Building footprints and landparcels]

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by @PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/250705/115), you could [**union**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) or [**intersect**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) the building footprints to the land parcels. I think an intersect would probably work best here. That will add the attributes of the land parcels to the building footprints. Then, run [**summary statistics**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) on the result and set your statistic to MAX on the footprint area field and your case field is your unique identifier for each parcel. This will result in a table with the largest footprint per parcel.

It is possible that the building footprints cross parcel boundaries. You will have to account for those somehow. Perhaps a [**spatial join**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) may give you better results than the intersect.

This is a fairly simple workflow and can easily be implemented in ModelBuilder.